# Modifying an exposed parameter of a geometry nodes setup via python

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, error

I have a Geometry Nodes setup, where I have an exposed parameter called `Inflate amount`:

[image]

I want to change this value via script.

I'm trying the following, but it doesn't work:

`bpy.data.objects["Cube_WearOperator"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"]`

I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed:
> Cube_WearOperator, Object datablock, error setting
> NodesModifier.Input_2

I tried to research the term 'context' with reference to Blender, and I have some idea of it, but not too much.

[image]

1. Execute the script first, so that the tab called 'Wear' appears on the sidepanel.
2. Uncomment line 118, then run again to reproduce the error.

Blender version 3.5.0

Comment: Hello and welcome. I tried it and it works fine. You have some other stuff in your blend file causing this problem. Can you make a simple setup that reproduces this problem and share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: i downloaded the file but can't reproduce your problem. what version are you using? im on 3.6. better use the latest version 3.6

Comment: I'm on 3.5.0. Will try to upgrade and test. Thanks.

Comment: @Nedudgi There is no script in the blend file.

Comment: @Karan, sorry, my bad. Script was external. I've included it in the .blend. I'm new at this, bear with me :) New link: (https://blend-exchange.com/b/lkwNpD6n/)

Comment: Please reduce the code to 10 lines. If you're just trying to change a read-only property for your context because it's drawing code, then it doesn't require a response. If you want to change the node tree property but change the modifier property, this also requires a separate explanation in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit/modify properties directly in `draw()` using `bpy.data.objects["Cube_WearOperator"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"] = 1`

You have to set the default value in the operator like this:

```
modifierGeoNodes = obj.modifiers['GeometryNodes']
modifierGeoNodes.node_group = bpy.data.node_groups["inflate"]
modifierGeoNodes.node_group.inputs['Inflate amount'].default_value = 0.01
modifierGeoNodes.node_group.update_tag()
```

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Wear",
    "blender": (2, 93, 0),
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

class AddEdgeWear(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "rhl.addedgewear"
    bl_label = "Add Edge Wear"

    def execute(self, context):

        objOperatedOn = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
        baseName = objOperatedOn.name
        
        
        obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(baseName+"_WearOperator")
        if not obj:
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
            obj = bpy.context.active_object
        else:
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
            obj.hide_set(False)
            obj.select_set(True)
            bpy.ops.object.delete()
            objOperatedOn.select_set(True)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objOperatedOn
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
            obj = bpy.context.active_object

        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        obj.select_set(True)
        obj.hide_set(True)

        obj.name = baseName+"_WearOperator"

        obj.modifiers.new("Remesh", type = "REMESH")
        obj.modifiers.new("GeometryNodes", type = "NODES")
        obj.modifiers.new("LaplacianSmooth", type = "LAPLACIANSMOOTH")
        obj.modifiers.new("Displace", type = "DISPLACE")
        
        modifierRemesh = obj.modifiers.get("Remesh")
        modifierGeoNodes = obj.modifiers['GeometryNodes']
        modifierGeoNodes.node_group = bpy.data.node_groups["inflate"]
        modifierGeoNodes.node_group.inputs['Inflate amount'].default_value = 0.01
        modifierGeoNodes.node_group.update_tag()
    
        modifierLaplacianSmooth = obj.modifiers["LaplacianSmooth"]
        modifierLaplacianSmooth.lambda_factor = 16
        
        modifierDisplace = obj.modifiers["Displace"]
        modifierDisplace.strength = .1
        displacementTexture = bpy.data.textures.get('EdgeWearDisplacementTexture')
        if not displacementTexture:
            displacementTexture = bpy.data.textures.new("EdgeWearDisplacementTexture", type='CLOUDS')
        modifierDisplace.texture = displacementTexture
        

        
        objOperatedOn.modifiers.new("WearBool", type = "BOOLEAN")
        modifierBoolean = objOperatedOn.modifiers['WearBool']
        modifierBoolean.operation = 'INTERSECT'
        modifierBoolean.solver = "FAST"
        modifierBoolean.object = obj
        
        
        print ("LOFASZ")
        #bpy.data.objects["EdgeWearOperator"].select_set(True)

        return {'FINISHED'}


class OBJECT_PT_wear(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Wear"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_wear"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Wear'



    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None and context.object.type == 'MESH'

    def draw(self, context):
        
        
        
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("rhl.addedgewear", text="Add Edge Wear")

        obj = context.object
        

        has_remesh_modifier = False
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'REMESH':
                has_remesh_modifier = True
                break
        if (has_remesh_modifier):
            modifierRemesh = obj.modifiers.get("Remesh")
            layout.label(text="Carver resolution in world units")
            layout.prop(modifierRemesh, "voxel_size", text="Resolution")


        
        has_geometry_nodes_modifier = False
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'NODES':
                has_geometry_nodes_modifier = True
                break
        if (has_geometry_nodes_modifier):
            modifierGeoNodes = obj.modifiers['GeometryNodes']
            layout.label(text="Edge width")
            layout.prop(modifierGeoNodes, '["Input_2"]', text="Edge width")
            #bpy.data.objects["wBox_WearOperator"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"] = 1


        has_laplacian_modifier = False
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'LAPLACIANSMOOTH':
                has_laplacian_modifier = True
                break
        if (has_laplacian_modifier):
            modifierLaplacianSmooth = obj.modifiers["LaplacianSmooth"]
            layout.label(text="Edge roundness")
            layout.prop(modifierLaplacianSmooth, "lambda_factor", text = "Roundness")

        has_displace_modifier = False
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'DISPLACE':
                has_displace_modifier = True
                break
        if (has_displace_modifier):
            modifierDisplace = obj.modifiers["Displace"]
            noiseTexture = modifierDisplace.texture
            layout.label(text="Edge noise size")
            layout.prop(noiseTexture, "noise_scale", text = "Noise size")
            layout.label(text="Edge noise strength")
            layout.prop(modifierDisplace, "strength", text = "Noise strength")
            


    def adjust_edge_width(value):
        # Define the range of "edgeWidth" values
        min_edge_width = 0.1
        max_edge_width = 0.0

        # Ensure the input value is within the range [0, 1]
        value = max(0, min(1, value))

        # Calculate the new edgeWidth based on the input value
        edge_width = min_edge_width + (max_edge_width - min_edge_width) * value

        # Set the edgeWidth value to all selected objects (you can change this as needed)
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if "edgeWidth" in obj:
                obj["edgeWidth"] = edge_width
        return edge_width
      



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_wear)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddEdgeWear)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.edgeWidth = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Edge Width",
        default=0.0,
        min=0.0,
        max=1.0,
        description="Edge width"
    )


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_wear)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddEdgeWear)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_custom_variable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```